# Script that only counts Established, TIME_WAIT, and Closed Wait connections using Netstat

Tags: windows, perl, shell, batch-file, netstat

I'm trying to make a script for Windows that will only count the number of Established, Time_Wait, and Closed_Wait connections on a system and print them in command prompt. I had already made a shell script that can do this on Linux boxes, but shell scripts to not work in Windows. I attempted to use a .bat in order to execute the script but that is not working (probably because it's still a shell script in Windows :/)The reason why it must only show Established, Time_Wait, and Closed_Wait is because the script is being used by a monitoring program that will fail if any other connection types show up. Can anyone make a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: What args are you using to generate the input, and please provide a sample of exactly the output should look like.

Comment: My original input from the Linux script is:                         ESTABLISHED=`netstat -nat | egrep 'ESTABLISHED' | wc -l`
TIME_WAIT=`netstat -nat | egrep 'TIME_WAIT' | wc -l`
CLOSE_WAIT=`netstat -nat | egrep 'CLOSE_WAIT' | wc -l`
SYN_SENT=`netstat -nat | egrep 'SYN_SEND' | wc -l`
SYN_RECV=`netstat -nat | egrep 'SYN_RECVEIVED' | wc -l`
echo $ESTABLISHED
echo $TIME_WAIT
echo $CLOSE_WAIT
echo $SYN_SENT
echo $SYN_RECV      The output should just the count of each connection status on 5 separate lines.

Comment: @monkeychef You should edit your original post with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following (should) work without making any changes on both *nix and Windows. I've tested it on Ubuntu w/ Perl v.5.18.0, Linux Mint w/ Perl v5.22.0 and Win2k8R2 (w/ Strawberry Perl v5.8.8).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @stat = split '\n', `netstat -nat`;

my @wanted = qw(
                ESTABLISHED
                TIME_WAIT
                CLOSED_WAIT
                SYN_SENT
                SYN_RECV
            );

my %data = map {$_ => 0} @wanted;

for (@stat){
    s/^\s+//;

    my $status;

    if ($^O eq 'MSWin32'){
        $status = (split)[3];
    }
    else {
        $status = (split)[5];
    }

    next if ! $status;

    $data{$status}++ if defined $data{$status};
}

print "$data{$_}\n" for @wanted;
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! I attempted to add two other status's (syn_sent and syn_received) by modifying line 6 and adding two lines at the end however that seems to break the script. Is there a certain way this needs to be done?

Comment: I've made some significant efficiency changes. If you want to add more entries, put them in the `@wanted` list. The output prints in the order the `@wanted` list is in. You can add/remove from that list and it will not affect anything other than the output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this was fantastic!